# Как добавить реакции к сообщению бота (самому боту) discord py

Tags: python, api, discord

Как добавить реакцию ботов на последнее сообщение самого бота

```
check = await ctx.send("Сообщение")
ross = bot.get_emoji(":poop:743175185167024238")
await check.add_reaction(ross)
```

Выдает ошибку `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not NoneType.`

Пробовал на прямую без bot.get_emoji, не получилось ошибка другая.
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji`

Answer (score 0):

Ваше первое исключение говорит о том , что вы передаёте в переменную неправильное название emoji привожу пример правильного названия `:eyes:`

Второе ваше исключение говорит вам о том , что такого emoji не существует , привожу опять таки пример существующего названия `:heart_eyes:`

Comment: Название emoji взято прямо из дискорда в моём случае, попробовал два ваших названия выходит 2ая ошибка.
По документации смотрю что нужно использовать такой формат await message.add_reaction("name:id")

Comment: Попробуйте , `bot.get_emoji(этот_id)` приводить к str

Comment: Насколько верно я вычитал из документации , правильно обозначать уже имеющийся emoji так `emoji = client.get_emoji(310177266011340803)`  , а не имеющийся так `emoji = '<:python3:232720527448342530>'`

Comment: `bot.get_emoji(id) - id` нужно передать как int исходя из документации, но пробовал и строкой, get_emoji возвращает всегда  None.
Получилось сделать только так await `check.add_reaction('')`, в самом дискорде перед смайликом ставить \ и после отправки в чат выдает Unicode emoji

Comment: @Athreem , странно , ведь в первом исключении пишет  , что `emoji argument must be str` т.е должен быть строкой

Comment: @Athreem , попробуйте это `emoji = client.get_emoji(310177266011340803) ` это из официальной документации, вот ссылка : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html

Comment: `"<:grinning:743222846431690872>"` - если использовать это в сообщении отправляйтесь emoji, но `get_emoji` и `add_reaction` не видят этот emoji.

Comment: `emoji = client.get_emoji(310177266011340803)` = `Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji`

Comment: https://youtu.be/-w7XYr22UEw?t=515 - видео новое и тут работает `add_reaction`, но в видео используются кастомный emoji, пробовал сделать по аналогии с дефолтными emoji не получается.

Comment: @Athreem , что-то неладное творится

Comment: ```check = await ctx.send("Сообщение")
emoji = bot.get_emoji(310177266011340803)
await check.add_reaction(emoji)```
Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not NoneType.

emoji = None

Comment: @Athreem , он ждёт от вас emoji в формате строки , а позже пишет , что такого emoji не найдено

Answer (score 0):

Забыл кавычки, пользовательские так идут

```
await message.add_reaction('<:sw:653933822022385665>')
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте более развёрнутые ответы: постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения. Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав "править" https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer